# No default audio output via Jack - Zoom H5 as USB audio interface - Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: sound, alsa, jack, external-soundcard

Before I start, I use the 4.11.2 low-latency kernel, realtime priority is enabled in `/etc/security/limits.conf`. Realtime user group etc. has been set up. Jack seems to work fine with ALSA.

I use the ‘Zoom H5’ audio recorder as a USB audio interface with Ubuntu 14.04. The Zoom H5 has 2 different audio-interface modes: (1) ‘Stereo’ - which allows you to record one stereo channel and (2) ‘Multitrack’, which allows you to record 4 mono channels at once.

**ISSUE ONE**

If I select ‘Stereo’, the Zoom H5 is recognised as a predecessor version (the Zoom H4) as an input option and as an output option by ALSA.

[image: Audio input options when Zoom H5 set to 'Stereo']

[image: Audio output options when Zoom H5 set to 'Stereo']

However, the audio signal from the Zoom H5 inputs is not going anywhere. The signal is neither picked up by my audio software nor is it hearable when I connect it in Jack directly to the system output (my internal Intel card).

Here is the output from Jack Messages:

```
00:54:54.668 D-BUS: JACK server was started (org.jackaudio.service aka jackdbus).
Sun May 21 00:54:54 2017: Starting jack server...
Sun May 21 00:54:54 2017: JACK server starting in realtime mode with priority 10
Sun May 21 00:54:54 2017: Acquired audio card Audio2
Sun May 21 00:54:54 2017: Acquired audio card Audio1
Sun May 21 00:54:54 2017: creating alsa driver ... hw:PCH|hw:H5|256|2|48000|0|0|nomon|swmeter|-|32bit
Sun May 21 00:54:54 2017: configuring for 48000Hz, period = 256 frames (5.3 ms), buffer = 2 periods
Sun May 21 00:54:54 2017: ALSA: final selected sample format for capture: 16bit little-endian
Sun May 21 00:54:54 2017: ALSA: use 2 periods for capture
Sun May 21 00:54:54 2017: ALSA: final selected sample format for playback: 32bit integer little-endian
Sun May 21 00:54:54 2017: ALSA: use 2 periods for playback
Sun May 21 00:54:54 2017: graph reorder: new port 'system:capture_1'
Sun May 21 00:54:54 2017: New client 'system' with PID 0
Sun May 21 00:54:54 2017: graph reorder: new port 'system:capture_2'
Sun May 21 00:54:54 2017: graph reorder: new port 'system:playback_1'
Sun May 21 00:54:54 2017: graph reorder: new port 'system:monitor_1'
Sun May 21 00:54:54 2017: graph reorder: new port 'system:playback_2'
Sun May 21 00:54:54 2017: graph reorder: new port 'system:monitor_2'
00:54:56.702 JACK connection change.
```

**ISSUE TWO**

If I select 'Multitrack' on the Zoom H5, the Zoom H5 is recognised only as an output device by ALSA. However, it is not recognised as an input device, although 4 mono input channels are provided by the Zoom H5. Also, when Multitrack is chosen, the Zoom device is recognised as 'H5' by my system.
Although ALSA doesn’t recognise the Zoom H5 recorder as an input device (when Multitrack is selected on the Zoom H5), Jack Audio recognises it and shows the 4 mono inputs. However, the problem is that the standard audio output, which is a simple internal Intel card `hw:1` is not shown and therefore not selectable in Jack. The output options ‘playback_1’ and ‘playback_2’ are the outputs of the Zoom H5 and the sound is coming out of the Zoom H5 instead of the pc speakers.

[image: Audio input options when Zoom H5 set to 'Multitrack']

[image: Audio output options when Zoom H5 set to 'Multitrack']

[image: Connections in Jack when Zoom H5 is used in Multitrack mode]

Here is the ‘Jack Message’ output after starting Jack

```
00:33:32.532 D-BUS: JACK server was started (org.jackaudio.service aka jackdbus).
Sun May 21 00:33:32 2017: Starting jack server...
Sun May 21 00:33:32 2017: JACK server starting in realtime mode with priority 10
Sun May 21 00:33:32 2017: Acquired audio card Audio2
Sun May 21 00:33:32 2017: Acquired audio card Audio1
Sun May 21 00:33:32 2017: creating alsa driver ... hw:1|hw:H5|256|2|48000|0|0|nomon|swmeter|-|32bit
Sun May 21 00:33:32 2017: configuring for 48000Hz, period = 256 frames (5.3 ms), buffer = 2 periods
Sun May 21 00:33:32 2017: ALSA: final selected sample format for capture: 24bit little-endian
Sun May 21 00:33:32 2017: ALSA: use 2 periods for capture
Sun May 21 00:33:32 2017: ALSA: final selected sample format for playback: 32bit integer little-endian
Sun May 21 00:33:32 2017: ALSA: use 2 periods for playback
Sun May 21 00:33:32 2017: graph reorder: new port 'system:capture_1'
Sun May 21 00:33:32 2017: New client 'system' with PID 0
Sun May 21 00:33:32 2017: graph reorder: new port 'system:capture_2'
Sun May 21 00:33:32 2017: graph reorder: new port 'system:capture_3'
Sun May 21 00:33:32 2017: graph reorder: new port 'system:capture_4'
Sun May 21 00:33:32 2017: graph reorder: new port 'system:playback_1'
Sun May 21 00:33:32 2017: graph reorder: new port 'system:monitor_1'
Sun May 21 00:33:32 2017: graph reorder: new port 'system:playback_2'
Sun May 21 00:33:32 2017: graph reorder: new port 'system:monitor_2'
```

Here is the output after I stopped Jack:

```
00:35:40.444 D-BUS: JACK server is stopping...
00:35:40.453 D-BUS: JACK server was stopped (org.jackaudio.service aka jackdbus).
Sun May 21 00:35:40 2017: Client 'qjackctl' with PID 2849 is out
Sun May 21 00:35:40 2017: Stopping jack server...
Sun May 21 00:35:40 2017: Client 'system' with PID 0 is out
Sun May 21 00:35:40 2017: Released audio card Audio2
Sun May 21 00:35:40 2017: Released audio card Audio1
```

I have checked which audio modules are currently activated on my system `cat /proc/asound/modules` and it shows that the Intel device is activated as well as the Zoom H5:

```
 0 snd_hda_intel
 1 snd_hda_intel
 2 snd_usb_audio
```

Also, here is the `aplay -l` output:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC3239 Analog [ALC3239 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: H5 [H5], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Here is the output of `sudo lsusb -l` for the Stereo mode:

```
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 1686:0045 ZOOM Corporation H4 Digital Recorder
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               1.10
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x1686 ZOOM Corporation
  idProduct          0x0045 H4 Digital Recorder
  bcdDevice            0.00
  iManufacturer           1 ZOOM Corporation
  iProduct                2 H5
  iSerial                 3 000000000000
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength          190
    bNumInterfaces          3
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              500mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           0
      bInterfaceClass         1 Audio
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Control Device
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                10
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      1 (HEADER)
        bcdADC               1.00
        wTotalLength           62
        bInCollection           2
        baInterfaceNr( 0)       1
        baInterfaceNr( 1)       2
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                12
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      2 (INPUT_TERMINAL)
        bTerminalID             1
        wTerminalType      0x0201 Microphone
        bAssocTerminal          0
        bNrChannels             2
        wChannelConfig     0x0003
          Left Front (L)
          Right Front (R)
        iChannelNames           0 
        iTerminal               0 
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                10
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      6 (FEATURE_UNIT)
        bUnitID                 2
        bSourceID               1
        bControlSize            1
        bmaControls( 0)      0x01
          Mute Control
        bmaControls( 1)      0x02
          Volume Control
        bmaControls( 2)      0x02
          Volume Control
        iFeature                0 
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 9
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      3 (OUTPUT_TERMINAL)
        bTerminalID             3
        wTerminalType      0x0101 USB Streaming
        bAssocTerminal          0
        bSourceID               2
        iTerminal               0 
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                12
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      2 (INPUT_TERMINAL)
        bTerminalID             4
        wTerminalType      0x0101 USB Streaming
        bAssocTerminal          0
        bNrChannels             2
        wChannelConfig     0x0003
          Left Front (L)
          Right Front (R)
        iChannelNames           0 
        iTerminal               0 
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 9
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      3 (OUTPUT_TERMINAL)
        bTerminalID             5
        wTerminalType      0x0302 Headphones
        bAssocTerminal          0
        bSourceID               4
        iTerminal               0 
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           0
      bInterfaceClass         1 Audio
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       1
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         1 Audio
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      AudioStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      1 (AS_GENERAL)
        bTerminalLink           4
        bDelay                  0 frames
        wFormatTag              1 PCM
      AudioStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                14
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      2 (FORMAT_TYPE)
        bFormatType             1 (FORMAT_TYPE_I)
        bNrChannels             2
        bSubframeSize           2
        bBitResolution         16
        bSamFreqType            2 Discrete
        tSamFreq[ 0]        44100
        tSamFreq[ 1]        48000
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 9
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes           13
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               Synchronous
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0100  1x 256 bytes
        bInterval               1
        bRefresh                0
        bSynchAddress           0
        AudioControl Endpoint Descriptor:
          bLength                 7
          bDescriptorType        37
          bDescriptorSubtype      1 (EP_GENERAL)
          bmAttributes         0x01
            Sampling Frequency
          bLockDelayUnits         0 Undefined
          wLockDelay              0 Undefined
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        2
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           0
      bInterfaceClass         1 Audio
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        2
      bAlternateSetting       1
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         1 Audio
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      AudioStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      1 (AS_GENERAL)
        bTerminalLink           3
        bDelay                  0 frames
        wFormatTag              1 PCM
      AudioStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                14
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      2 (FORMAT_TYPE)
        bFormatType             1 (FORMAT_TYPE_I)
        bNrChannels             2
        bSubframeSize           2
        bBitResolution         16
        bSamFreqType            2 Discrete
        tSamFreq[ 0]        44100
        tSamFreq[ 1]        48000
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 9
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes           13
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               Synchronous
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0100  1x 256 bytes
        bInterval               1
        bRefresh                0
        bSynchAddress           0
        AudioControl Endpoint Descriptor:
          bLength                 7
          bDescriptorType        37
          bDescriptorSubtype      1 (EP_GENERAL)
          bmAttributes         0x01
            Sampling Frequency
          bLockDelayUnits         0 Undefined
          wLockDelay              0 Undefined
Device Status:     0x0000
  (Bus Powered)
```

Here is the output of `sudo lsusb -l` for the Multitrack mode:

```
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 1686:01c5 ZOOM Corporation 
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass          239 Miscellaneous Device
  bDeviceSubClass         2 ?
  bDeviceProtocol         1 Interface Association
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x1686 ZOOM Corporation
  idProduct          0x01c5 
  bcdDevice            0.00
  iManufacturer           1 ZOOM Corporation
  iProduct                2 H5
  iSerial                 3 000000000000
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength          237
    bNumInterfaces          3
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              500mA
    Interface Association:
      bLength                 8
      bDescriptorType        11
      bFirstInterface         0
      bInterfaceCount         3
      bFunctionClass          1 Audio
      bFunctionSubClass       0 
      bFunctionProtocol      32 
      iFunction               0 
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           0
      bInterfaceClass         1 Audio
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Control Device
      bInterfaceProtocol     32 
      iInterface              0 
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 9
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      1 (HEADER)
        bcdADC               2.00
        bCategory               9
        wTotalLength          101
        bmControl            0x00
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 8
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype     10 (CLOCK_SOURCE)
        bClockID                6
        bmAttributes         0x03 Internal programmable Clock 
        bmControls           0x03
          Clock Frequency Control (read/write)
        bAssocTerminal          0
        iClockSource            0 
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                17
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      2 (INPUT_TERMINAL)
        bTerminalID             1
        wTerminalType      0x0101 USB Streaming
        bAssocTerminal          0
        bCSourceID              6
        bNrChannels             2
        bmChannelConfig   0x00000000
        bmControls    0x0000
        iChannelNames           0 
        iTerminal               0 
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                12
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      3 (OUTPUT_TERMINAL)
        bTerminalID             2
        wTerminalType      0x0302 Headphones
        bAssocTerminal          0
        bSourceID               1
        bCSourceID              6
        bmControls         0x0000
        iTerminal               0 
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                17
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      2 (INPUT_TERMINAL)
        bTerminalID             3
        wTerminalType      0x0201 Microphone
        bAssocTerminal          0
        bCSourceID              6
        bNrChannels             4
        bmChannelConfig   0x00000000
        bmControls    0x0000
        iChannelNames           0 
        iTerminal               0 
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                12
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      3 (OUTPUT_TERMINAL)
        bTerminalID             4
        wTerminalType      0x0101 USB Streaming
        bAssocTerminal          0
        bSourceID               5
        bCSourceID              6
        bmControls         0x0000
        iTerminal               0 
      AudioControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                26
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      6 (FEATURE_UNIT)
        bUnitID                 5
        bSourceID               3
        bmaControls( 0)      0x00000003
          Mute Control (read/write)
        bmaControls( 1)      0x0000000c
          Volume Control (read/write)
        bmaControls( 2)      0x0000000c
          Volume Control (read/write)
        bmaControls( 3)      0x0000000c
          Volume Control (read/write)
        bmaControls( 4)      0x0000000c
          Volume Control (read/write)
        iFeature                0 
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           0
      bInterfaceClass         1 Audio
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol     32 
      iInterface              0 
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       1
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         1 Audio
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol     32 
      iInterface              0 
      AudioStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                16
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      1 (AS_GENERAL)
        bTerminalLink           1
        bmControls           0x00
        bFormatType             1
        bmFormats         0x00000001
          PCM
        bNrChannels             2
        bmChannelConfig   0x00000000
        iChannelNames           0 
      AudioStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 6
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      2 (FORMAT_TYPE)
        bFormatType             1 (FORMAT_TYPE_I)
        bSubslotSize            3
        bBitResolution         24
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes           13
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               Synchronous
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               1
        AudioControl Endpoint Descriptor:
          bLength                 8
          bDescriptorType        37
          bDescriptorSubtype      1 (EP_GENERAL)
          bmAttributes         0x00
          bmControls           0x00
          bLockDelayUnits         0 Undefined
          wLockDelay              0
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        2
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           0
      bInterfaceClass         1 Audio
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol     32 
      iInterface              0 
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        2
      bAlternateSetting       1
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         1 Audio
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol     32 
      iInterface              0 
      AudioStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                16
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      1 (AS_GENERAL)
        bTerminalLink           4
        bmControls           0x00
        bFormatType             1
        bmFormats         0x00000001
          PCM
        bNrChannels             4
        bmChannelConfig   0x00000000
        iChannelNames           0 
      AudioStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 6
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      2 (FORMAT_TYPE)
        bFormatType             1 (FORMAT_TYPE_I)
        bSubslotSize            3
        bBitResolution         24
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes           13
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               Synchronous
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0100  1x 256 bytes
        bInterval               1
        AudioControl Endpoint Descriptor:
          bLength                 8
          bDescriptorType        37
          bDescriptorSubtype      1 (EP_GENERAL)
          bmAttributes         0x00
          bmControls           0x00
          bLockDelayUnits         0 Undefined
          wLockDelay              0
Device Qualifier (for other device speed):
  bLength                10
  bDescriptorType         6
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  bNumConfigurations      1
Device Status:     0x0000
  (Bus Powered)
```

**My questions are:**

Issue one: Any chance to get the audio signal routed to a software / the Intel speakers (hw:1)?

Issue two: How to get the Intel output back while keeping the Zoom H5 input as Multitrack?

Comment: The screenshots are from PulseAudio, which Jack does not use. Please show the output of `lsusb -v` for the device in both modes.

Comment: Hi CL, I have added the the output of ``sudo lsusb -l`` in my question! Thanks for having a look into this. Cheers!

Comment: All the channels are available; PulseAudio just doesn't understand four-channel inputs. There are [several ways](http://jackaudio.org/faq/multiple_devices.html) of getting Jack to use multiple cards.

Comment: The problem is that Jack doesn't provide me with the ``hw:PCH`` output. When I choose it in the settings, it complains upon starting it.